# Easiest way to programmatically clip raster to rectangular extent

Tags: python, gdal, clip

I am looking for the easiest way to programmatically clip a raster to a rectangular extent for testing purposes. I have GDAL and Python installed on a virtual machine and would like to run the code from Jupyter (python/command line) or command line directly. I do not have a polygon with the extent yet. I am **not** looking for answers that involve QGIS/ ArcGIS or some other GUI.

I found [this](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#clip-a-geotiff-with-shapefile) resource but I was hoping for something more succinct like:

```
some-command inputraster.tif outputraster.tif -extent [lower left corner, upper right corner]
```

or

1. Create polygon
2. Clip using polygon

I am pretty sure there must be some gdal command out there.

Comment: Gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html with `-projwin ulx uly lrx lry`. I am pretty sure that you could have found it by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do what you want using [`gdalwarp`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) and the `-te` option.

> -te xmin ymin xmax ymax:
>
> set georeferenced extents of output file to be created (in target SRS by default, or in the SRS specified with -te_srs)